# why enqueued styles in header.php shows in footer?

Tags: css, headers, wp-enqueue-style

I`m using this code in functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'addMyStyle');
function addMyStyle() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', false, '1.0', 'all', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-rtl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-rtl.css', false, '1.0', 'all', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
}
```

and `<?php wp_head(); ?>` tag is right before `</head>` tag. but style files load in footer tags. I want these styles load in head tags.

Inside my `<head>` tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl" xml:lang="fa" lang="fa">
<?php global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo(); ?>
<head>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#1B5064" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA--1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA--1');
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    obj.style.height = 0;
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="" />

<?php 
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    ?>
    <style>.woocommerce-cart-form .container {overflow:scroll;}</style>
    <?php
}
?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: What does the code look like for your header? Also, you are passing too many arguments into `wp_enqueue_style`. You have 6 and the function only takes 5: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: I put my head tag section. and yes last false is extra argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that enqueued scripts and styles are output on `wp_head` at priority *8*, but your `addMyStyle()` functioning is running at priority 10, the default. This means that it's too late to enqueue scripts and styles for the header. You could use a lower priority, but `wp_head` is the wrong hook to use here anyway. You should be using `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: Yes jacob, using wp_enqueue_scripts is better than wp_head. it works. thanks